# Shell/Bash - positional parameter for script and function colliding

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, command-line-interface

My script is to accept one parameter `dms`. Once obtained it creates multiple variables that are used as argument for `retry_cli`. Issue I'm having is with positional parameter usage. How to workaround the mechanism for script to create variables and use them as parameters for each function's run?

Currently it seems that function is using positional parameters injected when script is triggered, not the ones created inside of it. [Documentation](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_11_01.html#sect_11_01_03) indicates that two `$1` positional arguments (for script and function) shouldn't be an issue.

```
dms_name=$1
aws_region="us-east-1"
dms_arn=`aws dms describe-replication-tasks --filter Name=replication-task-id,Values="$dms_name" --query=ReplicationTasks[0].ReplicationTaskArn --output text --region "$aws_region"`

ri_arn=`aws dms describe-replication-tasks --filter Name=replication-task-id,Values=$dms_name --query=ReplicationTasks[0].ReplicationInstanceArn --region "$aws_region"`
target_arn=`aws dms describe-replication-tasks --filter Name=replication-task-id,Values=$dms_name --query=ReplicationTasks[0].TargetEndpointArn --region "$aws_region"`

ri_status=`aws dms describe-connections --filter Name=replication-instance-arn,Values=$ri_arn --query=Connections[0].Status --region "$aws_region"`
target_status=`aws dms describe-connections --filter Name=endpoint-arn,Values=$target_arn --query=Connections[0].Status --region "$aws_region"`

retry_cli () {
        local max_retry=100
        local counter=0
        local sleep_seconds=15 
        local aws_region="us-east-1"  
        until [[ $1 =~ "success" ]]
        do 
            status=`aws dms describe-connections --filter Name=$2,Values="$3" --query=Connections[0].Status --region "$aws_region"`
            [[ counter -eq $max_retry ]] && echo "connection status of $3 failed!" && exit 1
            ((counter++))
            sleep $sleep_seconds
        done
        echo "connection for $3 OK!"
}

retry_cli "$ri_status" replication-instance-arn "$ri_arn"
retry_cli "$target_status" endpoint-arn "$target_arn"

echo startting dms
aws dms start-replication-task --replication-task-arn "$dms_arn" --start-replication-task-type resume-processing --region "$aws_region"
echo done
```

Expected behaviour:

1. script is ran: `sh script.sh dms_name`
2. every `dms_` variable is populated
3. `retry_cli` is called with 3 arguments. When `$*_status` is not like `success` string, then the function must obtain latest `status` with `aws cli` command and repeat it as long as it returns `success`
4. move to the second function call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm **assuming** what the function's `until` loop is doing is repeatedly running a command until it receives a status message that includes the string `success`.

For the first pass the `until` loop is testing the function's first input parameter (`$1`) for the string `success`.

Subsequent passes through the `until` loop are *still* testing the function's first input parameter (`$1`) for the string `success`.

I'm guessing for subsequent passes what you want to do is test the latest `status` for the string `success`; if this is the case then perhaps a small code change:

```
retry_cli () {
    ...
    local status="$1"                           # new line
    until [[ "${status}" =~ "success" ]]        # modified line
    do
        ....
    done
    ...
}
```

If this doesn't address the issue then OP may want to provide some more details on the issue (eg, loop never exits, loop is never entered, ???).

Comment: Will this modification still remember to check `status` from function call to later (if error) check `status` from inside function's call?

Comment: @marcin2x4 in the suggested code modification `status` is being defined locally (to the function) so each call to the function will start with a new copy of `status`; if you need some form of `status` to be 'passed up' to the calling process then I'd suggest updating the question with this fact as well as an example of how you're using said value(s) in the parent script; under such a scenario we probably want to look at changing `status` from a local variable to a nameref ... but at this point I don't want to go overboard writing that up if that doesn't address the issue

Comment: I updated the expected behavior description @markp-fuso

Comment: @marcin2x4 I think this answer still does what you want; have you tried it? if it doesn't do what you want please provide some details on what's wrong/incorrect

Comment: Yes, the script worked. Fun thing is that my version also worked... There was a lag in bamboo deployment. Which one should I stick to? @markp-fuso

Comment: if your version 'worked' it's because the status included the string `success` before the function was even called; check the content of your `$ri_status` and `$target_status` variables before calling the function; there's no way the current function (as displayed in the question) is going to receive a non-success string, conduct a pass through the loop, and see `$1` change (only the `status` variable is going to change and it's not being tested in the `until` condition); as a test of the current code: `unset ri_status; retry_cli "$ri_status" replication-instance-arn "$ri_arn"`

Comment: Works as I explained in the post. Big thanks @markp-fuso. It seems as you explained. When `status` was not `success` the loop was initiated but there was no value passed again in the `status`. AKA - When it got other status, it wasn't passed inside the loop.